# Is there a way to click on a 1 full screen section that scrolls to the next section and so forth based on using one class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is there a way to click on a 1 full screen section that scrolls to the next section and so forth based on using one css class.

Something similar to this, but having all the classes as the same class.

https://codepen.io/jvondoom/pen/VvbrdY

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div.top').click(function() {
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("div.middle").offset().top
      }, 1000)
    }),
    $('div.middle').click(function() {
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("div.bottom").offset().top
      }, 1000)
    }),
    $('div.bottom').click(function() {
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("div.top").offset().top
      }, 1000)
    })
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline;
}

.top {
  background-color: green;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.middle {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.bottom {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top">
  <h1>Top</h1>
</div>
<div class="middle">
  <h1>Middle</h1>
</div>
<div class="bottom">
  <h1>Bottom</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, by using jQuery .next(): https://api.jquery.com/next/

Comment: You could use a simple hyperlink and #anchors if you don't need them for routing. Clicking a `<a href="#middle">middle</a>` will scroll the element with `id="middle"` into view. Not sure if the base animation is adequate for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this work with a common class you can add a single event handler to all the elements which retrieve the `next()` sibling element and scrolls to it. If there is no following sibling then you can scroll back to the first one. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div.section').click(function() {
    var $next = $(this).next('.section');
    if ($next.length == 0)
      $next = $('.section:first');
      
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $next.offset().top
    }, 1000)
  });
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline;
}

.section {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.top {
  background-color: green;
}

.middle {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.bottom {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section top">
  <h1>Top</h1>
</div>
<div class="section middle">
  <h1>Middle</h1>
</div>
<div class="section bottom">
  <h1>Bottom</h1>
</div>
```

Note that I also DRYed up the CSS given the new common class on all the `div` elements.